# Linq - Filter list property that is inside another list by a list of strings

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of an object called `Ocorrencia` and it has a property called `Tecnicos` that is a list of the object `OcorrenciaTecnico`. This object has a propert called `Nome` that it a `String`. I want to filter the list of `Ocorrencia` by this last property (`Nome`), by a list of `String`'s.

Too complex to me. How can I achieve this?

I've tried this:

```
ocorrencias = ocorrencias.Select(
    x => x.Tecnicos.Where(
        y => ocorrenciaFiltro.TecnicosFiltro.Any(
            z => z.Equals(y.Nome))));
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   "`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MasterCoin.Models.OcorrenciaTecnico>>`"
>   to
>   "`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MasterCoin.Models.Ocorrencia>`".
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: show us some code what you tried

Comment: @kunal-mukherjee The question is updated with the code

Comment: please post the model classes also

Comment: where does `ocorrenciaFiltro` come from? what is it supposed to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you confused `Select` (a *projection*) and `Where` (a *filter*).
Try this:

```
var filteredOcorrencias = ocorrencias.Where(
    x => x.Tecnicos.Any(
        y => ocorrenciaFiltro.TecnicosFiltro.Contains(y.Nome))).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! I only had to add a verification to check the list of `Tecnico` is not null.
`var filteredOcorrencias = ocorrencias.Where(
    x => x.Tecnicos != null &&  x.Tecnicos.Any(
        y => ocorrenciaFiltro.TecnicosFiltro.Contains(y.Nome))).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

How about that ?

```cs
var nomes = new List<string> {"Taian", "Taian2"};
var allTaian = Ocorrencia.Where(o => o.Tecnicos.Any(t => nomes.Contains(t.Nome)));
```